# Select Dates where time is less or equal to '12:00' Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I require a query that selects rows where the time is less or equal to 12:00
I had something like this in mind:

```
SELECT daterow FROM datecolumn WHERE daterow <= TO_DATE('12:00, HH24:MI')
```

However i get an error:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

How would i go about to get all rows that have a time less than 12:00 mid-day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select all rows where time portion of the `daterow` column value is less than or equal to mid-day `12:00` you can use `to_char()` function to extract hour and minutes and `to_number()` to convert it to a number for further comparison:

```
 -- sample of data. Just for the sake of demonstration
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select sysdate - to_dsinterval('P0DT3H')  from dual union all
  3    select sysdate - to_dsinterval('P0DT2H')  from dual union all
  4    select sysdate - to_dsinterval('P0DT1H')  from dual union all
  5    select sysdate + to_dsinterval('P0DT3H')  from dual union all
  6    select sysdate + to_dsinterval('-P2DT0H') from dual
  7  )
  8  select to_char(col, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as res
  9    from t1 t
 10  where to_number(to_char(col, 'hh24mi')) <= 1200
 11  ;
```

Result:

```
RES
-------------------
26.08.2013 08:10:59
26.08.2013 09:10:59
26.08.2013 10:10:59
24.08.2013 11:10:59
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly! :b Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT daterow FROM datecolumn WHERE daterow <= TO_DATE('12:00', 'HH24:MI');
```

Comment: I'm amazed, how the hell did I not see that 3 hours ago?
God damnit. Thanks Dba -.-

Comment: Date part returned by the `To_Date('12:00 hh24:mi')` will be the first day of the month - `01.08.2013 12:00:00` and if `daterow` has a value, lets say `02.08.2013 09:00:00`, the condition `daterow <= TO_DATE('12:00', 'HH24:MI')` will be false, despite the fact the the time portion of the `daterow` is less than `12:00`.

Comment: Yep, seems like this solution doesn't work, thanks for pointing that out Nicholas.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
    SELECT daterow FROM datecolumn
 WHERE TO_DATE(daterow,'HH24:MI') <= TO_DATE('12:00', 'HH24:MI');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but `<= TO_DATE('12:00', 'HH24:MI')` does not work. It *does not* extract the hour and minute from each date and compares it to 12:00. Instead it constructs the date representing high noon on the fisrt of the current month and compares each date to this date.

If you want to *extract* something from a date, use the `extract` function.

**Attention:** When using extract on a date, and want to extract hours, minutes or seconds, you have first to convert the date to a timestamp.

Example:

```
SELECT
  extract(hour FROM cast(A AS TIMESTAMP)) AS h,
  extract(MINUTE FROM cast(A AS TIMESTAMP)) AS m
FROM
  DEMO
;
```

You can find a complete example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6afc2/4). The example also shows that the `to_date` method doesn't work.